# Will Allah accept my pray if my heart is impure and if not do I have to redo it

Tags: salat, fiqh

Will Allah accept my prayer if my heart is impure and if not do I have to redo it

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have come to pray is proof in itself that you have purity in heart.

If it is the Iman or Taqwa that you think is missing in your heart then, I recommend you to keep up with the 5 times salah and inshaAllah your iman and Taqwa will also keep up.

Allah says as per hadith Muslim 6833:

> Whoever comes to me walking, I will come running towards him.

Also in quran says in 2:186

> And if My servants ask you about Me, I am near answering the calls of
>   those who call to Me. So let them respond to Me and believe in Me that
>   they may be guided.

So, the fact that you are praying means you still have purity in heart and Allah still responds.

Comment: Jazak allah khair I try telling my self that I but sometimes I just don’t believe what I say but that help coming from a different person and reminding me of those Hadith that I forgot ✌️

Comment: @Unknown I am glad hear that it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted so that it does not appear as unanswered.